# How to get 'captureDate' from values and send it as a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, promise, discord.js

So I'm adding a feature to my discord bot to collect the users most recent gameclip, at the moment I'm able to collect all the information in my console log but struggling to understand how to send it in a message. I'm pretty new to this stuff.

**This is a snippet of my code right now:**

```
    const userXuid = await XboxLiveAPI.getPlayerXUID(gamertag, authInfo).catch(err => message.reply('That gamertag could not be found. Make sure spaces are replaced with \'_\''));
    const scores = await XboxLiveAPI.getPlayerScreenshotsFromMediaHub(userXuid, authInfo, num);

    console.log(scores);
```

**And this is what gets returned to the console:**

```
{
  continuationToken: 'YWJjZGVfdnd4eXoxMDA1',
  values: [ 
    {
      captureDate: '2016-09-13T19:11:11Z',
      contentId: 'e61118b6-c940-4hc9-a32a-49dd53ab4192',
      contentLocators: [Array],
      CreationType: 'Edited',
      localId: '501bf44b-c1b2-4519-b78e-a1f88097f8d1',
      ownerXuid: 25332749247888726,
      resolutionHeight: 720,
      resolutionWidth: 1280,
      sandboxId: 'RETAIL',
      sharedTo: [],
      titleId: 1129121809,
      titleName: 'OF: Dragon Rising',
      dateUploaded: '2016-09-13T19:12:34.6226406Z',
      uploadLanguage: 'en-GB',
      uploadRegion: 'GB',
      uploadTitleId: 201477059,
      uploadDeviceType: 'XboxOne',
      commentCount: 0,
      likeCount: 0,
      shareCount: 0,
      viewCount: 2,
      contentState: 'Published',
      enforcementState: 'None',
      safetyThreshold: 'None',
      sessions: [],
      tournaments: []
    }
  ]
}
```

**Conclusion**

So how would I, for example, get captureDate to send in:

message.channel.send(???)

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply talking about *accessing* `captureDate`, you'll use `scores.values[0].captureDate`.

Comment: Cheers for this Feixu :)